# CreateMap<T,U> for Nullable<TMember> to TMember

Tags: c#, automapper

Lets say I have an internal EF model:

```
public class EFModel
{
    public int key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? OptionalId { get; set;}
}
```

And my external facing model with the same data types except that none are Nullable:

```
public class Extmodel
{
    public int key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OptionalId { get; set; }
}
```

In general I'd have to go through `CreateMap` and explicitly cast:

```
CreateMap<EfModel,ExtModel>
    .ForMember(a => a.OptionalId, b => b.MapFrom(c => (int)c.OptionalId))
    .ReverseMap();
```

But imagine having a very large database, there should be some way to speed this up. I tried to a helper function that works on 'System.Reflection' and generics to sort this out for me.

```
    public void MapWrap<T, U>() where T : new()
    {
        var newT = new T();
        var map = CreateMap<T, U>();

        foreach (var member in newT.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            Type memberType = member.PropertyType;

            var nullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(memberType) == null;
            var notString = memberType != typeof(string);

            if (nullable && notString)
            {
                map.ForMember(dest => dest.GetType().GetMethod(member.Name),
                    src => src.MapFrom(
                        dt => Convert.ChangeType(dt.GetType().GetMethod(member.Name), Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(memberType))));
            }
        }
        map.ReverseMap();
    }
```

Assumptions:

1. All internal and external names are identical
2. All castings are strictly Nullable to T

I am getting an error 'Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.' Am I thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: The MapFrom is not needed. What's the performance problem here? Are you on the latest version?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu We are currently using version 5.0.2, which is older. Was this fixed in the later patches?

Comment: A nullable should map to the default value.